# Poor Buck Converter Current Limiting?

Tags: buck, shunt

I am planning on using the [XL7026 buck converter IC](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL7026%20datasheet-English.pdf) in an upcoming project because of its dirt cheap cost, small package and wide input voltage range.

However, there is one concerning aspect of the chips's design I have come across:

[image]

Notice the floating ground created thanks to the low-side shunt, R3. Even a few tens of millivolts drop with current will disturb more sensitive ICs. I am imagining that removing the shunt will have no effect on the converter's normal operation, effectively creating a very low voltage drop. This will, sadly, make the IC's current limiting useless and potentially damage the chip if I draw too much, such as capacitor charging at startup.

Would it be possible to use a high side shunt and inject the voltage differential across it into OGND (re-referenced to GND, of course)?

Comment: I don't see how you can assert 0gnd for current limiting and keep Vfb stable. with inverting current to voltage becoming positive feedback.

Comment: Why do you see the OGND - GND volt drop as a problem? Just don't connect any other circuitry to GND and you should be fine.

Comment: @Andyaka Was thinking the same. But those "sensitive ICs" could suffer from common mode noise then, though?

Comment: @Huisman the OP needs to come clean on this because the risks in changing the way the current limit works to make it topside might be significant.

Comment: @Andyaka I agree. I think changing the current limit measurement this way will increase the costs of this "cheap" solution way more than just picking a different SMPS controller.

Answer (score 1):

The low side current sensing makes it easier to use NPN input comparators and linear circuits and apparently reduce cost.  This makes it suitable for applications where it does not need input and outputs to share the same ground, such as Telecom and e-bikes.

Trying to convert it to a high side current sensing current limited regulator, does not make it "poor" ( logically... *unless you are really cheap;)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your proposal - if you take care of ceratain side conditions: The current limit does not appear to be low-pass filtered inside the chip, so it is not primarily about continous output current, but about monentary inductor current. This means that the amplifier for the high-side current has to be fast enough to terminate the pulse if the current starts to rise above the set limit. This is especially important if the current limit is set near the saturation current of the coil.

The oscillator frequency of the chip is 150kHz. If you declare a 1% widening of the duty cycle acceptable, the maximum allowed delay introduced by the current sense amplifier you are adding is 1/15µs, i.e. 60ns. If you don't get the current sense amplifier that fast, you can counter it by setting a lower threshold to get more time for turn-off. Keep in mind that the current rise speed is proportional to the input voltage, though.

Also, you should make sure that the current amplifier is operational during power-up, as current limiting is needed especially on the first cycles, when there is no feedback signal yet.